# DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-jdbc

I am getting this exception:

```
Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

My Propertis file is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://PADBQUA01
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.username=userName
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

And depenedencis in Pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc42</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.8112</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Why do I get this error?

I have tried already to add the expected dependencies

Comment: `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")` => change `spring.datasource.driverClassName` to `spring.datasource.hikari.driverClassName`

Comment: I still get the error...

Comment: Gotta update all `spring.datasource` to append `hikari`